# Como mandar informacion desde un array de dos dimensiones a un procedimiento almacenado en c#

Tags: c#, excel, stored-procedure

Me encuentro trabajando en una aplicación en la cual, tomando un archivo excel, su información la guardo en un array de dos dimensiones, el código que tengo para esto es el siguiente:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ruta);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

lineaExcel = new string[rowCount, colCount];

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        //escribimos los valores del excel en la variable
        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
        {
            lineaExcel[i-1, j-1] = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();

        }
    }
}

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

xlWorkbook.Close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

La información se guarda bien y si quiero la puedo traspasar a un datagrid.

He trabajado con listas y en ellas guardando información y después estas las tomo y las mando al procedimiento de la siguiente forma:

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("zf_Boleta_Crear", LaConexion);
comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

int i = 0;
while (i <= ContArchivo - 1)
{
    comando.Parameters.Clear();

    IdMonedaCif = Datos.ObtenerIdMonedaCIF(mCIF[i]);
    IdMonedaVenta = Datos.ObtenerIdMonedaCIF(mVenta[i]);
    IdTipoDoc = Datos.ObtenerIdTipoDoc(salida[i]);
    Fecha = Datos.ObtenerFecha(fDocumento[i]);

    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idboleta", DBNull.Value); // en la tabla es autoincremental 
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCliente", IDCliente);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdMonedaCIF", IdMonedaCif); //zf_Moneda hay que sacar el valor de acá
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdMonedaVenta", IdMonedaVenta); //zf_Moneda
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTipoDoc", IdTipoDoc); //zf_TipoDoc hay que sacar el valor de acá
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoIngreso", 'A');
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Archivo", NombreArchivo);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sTipoDocumento", salida[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNroBoleta", Int32.Parse(nDocumento[i]));
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sLineas", lDocumento[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sFecha", Fecha);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNroContrato", nContrato[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sTipoMovimiento", tDocEntrada[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sAñoZ", aDocEntrada[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sNumeroZ", nEntrada[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sItemZ", iDocEntrada[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sMoneda", mCIF[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sValorCIF", vCIF[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sMonedaVenta", mVenta[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sValorVenta", vVenta[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cadena", cadena[i]);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", "P");
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreadoPor", NombreCliente);

    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    i++;
}
LaConexion.Close();
```

Me funciona bien pero no se me ocurre cómo tendría que ser para el caso en el que tengo la información en un array de dos dimensiones.

¿Se puede hacer?
Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar y se haya entendido bien mi problema.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: un array de dos dimensiones seria un array[x][y]. seria igual.. o es un array que tiene adentro otro array?

Comment: array del tipo array[x][y]. Aunque por codigo tengo xlRange.Cells[i, j]. ¿Es lo mismo?

Comment: Mi error.. es como vos decis.. no como puse yo...

Comment: Entonces, la pregunta cual seria?

Comment: que yo tengo un ejemplo de como pasar los datos a un procedimiento pero es dato a dato, como pongo arriba, pero no sé cómo tendría que ser para cuando los datos los tengo en un array

Comment: Sigo sin entender, porque en tu codigo, al hacer comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sMoneda", mCIF[i]); estas pasando datos desde un array. Tal vez no entendiste tu codigo?

Comment: NO, estoy dando un ejemplo de como paso los datos desde un array a un procedimiento, lo que necesito es saber cómo paso datos de un array de dos dimensiones a un procedimiento

Comment: De la misma forma en que pasas datos de un array de una dimension, solo que tenes que especificar que posicion de la matriz queres. Tu pregunta tal vez es como recorrer un array de dos posiciones?

Comment: o sea, yo sé que se logra usando un for con un for anidado, esto lo he trabajado antes pero nunca para un procedimiento almacenado, y creo que me estoy confundiendo un poco por ese lado

Comment: Creo que tendrias que armar un ejemplo, porque te estas mareando con algo que tenes resuelto. No necesitas un for anidado, porque no queres recorrer las columnas. En el codigo que tenes, recorres las filas. Es lo mismo, solo que vos sabes que dato hay en cada columna, entonces no necesitas recorrerlo...